# How to properly indicate that last 24 hours data may or may not included in the sentence?

Tags: sentence

I have a visual chart on my website and I update this chart once or twice each day automatically. However, I would like to tell my users that this chart (contains data usages) may or may not include **last 24 hours**. And let them know that I will make sure everything is included when an invoice is issued.

Is this sentence correct?

> Data* may or may not contain usages for past 24 hours. Your invoiced total will be displayed once an invoice is issued.

```
* Data: Represents data in visual chart.
```

How can I make sure viewers acknowledge this properly?

Comment: Before I try to help, could you explain something?  Do you mean that you update at two specific times  (around 9 morning and evening or 8 in the morning and 5 in the afternoon, or whatever it is) or that you update twice but the times vary almost at random?

Comment: @Tuffy Sure! Everyday at night 00:00 UTC+0, System does update. Addition to this, maybe system needs an update due to some specific reason and trigger another update at a random time. Could be morning could be evening or could be never (Just at night as usual)

Comment: So is what is being updated a kind of record of the times a user uses the service (the data?)  Or does the service consist of providing whatever the data is and that is what gets updated once or twice a day?

Comment: First one. Service is used by user. (a kind of record of the times a user uses the service (the data?)) For example user upload a file to server. Then someone download that file. Software will log this activity, calculate how many times file downloaded and I will show this data to users in visual chart. Data (upload/download amount) updated once a day at night and maybe twice. Second update will be random.

Comment: In other words, the data is up-to-date within the last 24 hours and generally less than that.

Comment: Every 24 hours, system does update. Scheduled. No matter of what system will run this job. However, generally but not always less than that but **not guaranteed**.

Comment: I think my suggestion gives a guarantee of daily updating but not of more than that.  If you want qualify "and generally more than that, you could replace 'generally' with 'often' and if you want to be even less committal, you could say 'sometimes'.